# The output is right but the codechef not accepting, What is wrong in my code? Is my logic wrong?

Tags: c, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int app,ora,coins,rem;
        scanf("%d %d %d",&app,&ora,&coins);
        if(app!=ora)
        {
            while(coins>0)
            {
                if(app<=ora)
                {
                    app++;
                    coins--;
                }
                else if(ora<=app)
                {
                    ora++;
                    coins--;
                }
            }
            if(app>=ora)
            {
                printf("%d",app-ora);
            }
            else if(ora>=app)
            {
                printf("%d",ora-app);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Context:
to have the minimum possible difference between the number of apples and oranges he has. To do so, he can purchase 1 apple or 1 orange by paying exactly 1 gold coin (that's some expensive fruit, eh?). Chef can purchase fruits at most K times (as he has only K gold coins in his pocket) to make the difference the minimum possible.

Input:
4
3 4 1
5 2 1
3 4 3
6 11 3

Output:
0
2
0
2

Comment: Well, the output is not `0 2 0 2` is it? It is `0202`.

Comment: Why do you use a loop? That is terribly inefficient. The outcome for each situation is  `MAX(0, MAX(app, ora) - MIN(app, ora) - coins)`.